# Return multiple selections from tk listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a listbox and would like to be able to return multiple selections from said listbox.

I have tried changing "seltext" variable to a list(map(int()))) format, but I get the error of bad listbox index.

I'm not sure how to go about this; any help is appreciated.

The way I'm currently identifying the selected variable:

```
        def selecting(self,event):
            sel = self.lbox.curselection()
            seltext = self.lbox.get(sel)
            self.labelVariable.set(seltext)
```

The way that I'm assigning a single selection.

```
        def OnButtonClick(self):
            global confirmedsel
            confirmedsel = ""
            sel = self.lbox.curselection()
            seltext = self.lbox.get(sel)
            confirmedsel = seltext
            print(confirmedsel)
            app.quit()
```

Comment: Your example is both too much code and not enough code. Too much in that we don't need the entry or scrollbar or some of the functions, too little in that you didn't show any code that calls `initialize` or fills in the list with data.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't think I needed to post the creation of the dataframe

Comment: We don’t need the data frame per se, we just need some hard-coded data that is similar to your real world data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `curselection` method of the listbox returns a tuple of indexes representing the items that were selected. You simply need to iterate over that list and call the `get` method to get each element.

You do this in one line using a list comprehension, which results in a list that contains the values of the selected items as strings:

```
seltext = [self.lbox.get(index) for index in self.lbox.curselection()]
```

If you find list comprehensions difficult to read, here is a solution using a simple loop:

```
results = []
for index in self.lbox.curselection():
    results.append(self.lbox.get(index))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def selecting(self,event):
        sel = self.lbox.curselection()
        seltext = list(map(int,self.lbox.get(sel)))
        self.labelVariable.set(seltext)
```

Have you tried this?
You can lookup use of curselection here:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm

Comment: Hi Neha, thanks for the reply!

I did try that. Selecting the first selection creates a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'

When I select an additional selection, I get a TclError: bad listbox index: must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number